When extruding a vertex during retopology, the vertex is not aligning with the mesh surface
I’m new to Blender and was working on retopologizing a model I created. I added the Shrinkwrap modifier and started extruding vertices for the retopology, and everything was going smoothly until I reached the chest area. When I tried to extrude the vertices there, they started to wobble unexpectedly. I’ve tried enabling and disabling the Clipping option in the Mirror modifier, but the issue persists. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Sometimes its a good idea while retopologizing to apply the shrinkwrap and then re-add a new one to "Update" the vertices to their shrinkwrapped positions. Just relying on SW and snapping can often lead to verts that look like the should be in one place but are technically in another, since you're using the modifier preview mode.
